# Excel JavaScript API - How to select cells until filled range end

Tags: javascript, office-js, excel-addins

What would be the JavaScript API version for VBA:

```
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
```

In essence, I want to do the same what `ctrl+down arrow` keycombo does. Extend current selection down to the last cell with value.

Comment: As written your question can only be answered by someone who knows both the VBA API and the JavaScript. You might get more answers if you describe what it is you are trying to do for people that aren't familiar with the VBA API.

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 2):

I've had to write a custom function. Here it is. But I was hoping for having a native API for such a frequently used piece of functionality. I'd argue, that it is top frequently used.

```
export const get_nonempty_range_down = async (startingCell, context) => {
  const distanceLimit = 999;
  const rangeToTest = startingCell.getResizedRange(distanceLimit, 0);
  rangeToTest.load("values");
  await context.sync();

  const matrixValues = rangeToTest.values;
  let finalCellPosition = null;
  matrixValues.some((row, i) => {
    if (row[0] === "") {
      finalCellPosition = i - 1;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });

  const result = startingCell.getResizedRange(finalCellPosition, 0);
  // Debug
  // result.load("address");
  // await context.sync();
  // console.log(result.address);
  return result;
};
```

And it is still imperfect as it traverses only a thousand cells down. Ok for my needs, but not a complete solution.

Comment: Nice. But if this is the answer then what you want to do is get a reference to the range, not _select_ the range as your question seemed to imply. If you can clarify the question to match this answer, I'll up vote it.